# ¿Qué sonido del español es el menos común en lenguas romances?

Tags: pronunciación, fonología, comparación-de-idiomas

De los (aprox.) 35 sonidos que se manejan en [todos los dialectos del español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_Alfabeto_Fon%C3%A9tico_Internacional#Al%C3%B3fonos_universales) (excluyendo sonidos regionales) ¿Cuál es el menos compartido con otras lenguas romances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta pregunta es algo difícil de responder puesto que hay muchas lenguas romances y muchos dialectos. Lo que haré será tomar en cuenta las lenguas “mayores”, con mayor cantidad de hablantes, y las realizaciones fonéticas más comunes. Considerando español, portugués, francés, italiano, rumano y catalán, creo que capturo la inmensa mayoría de los hablantes romances.

Considerándolo así, diría que el “sonido menos compartido” es la fricativa dental sorda /θ/ (escrita *z* o bien *c* delante de *e, i*) de los dialectos con distinción (básicamente el estándar europeo), que no existe en ningún otro idioma romance.

Un segundo lugar disputado le correspondería a la fricativa velar sorda /x/ (escrita *j*). Este último sonido aparece como alófono de la /r/ en portugués, pero es exclusivamente en español donde aparece como parte de una serie de consonantes velares (con /k/ y /g/).

Comment: /θ/ appears in Galician, Leonese, and various dialects of Occitan, Sardinian, Venetian, and Italian (i.e. Tuscan). [x] is an allophone of /h/ in Romanian.

Comment: @brazofuerte: In Italian?

Comment: I did limit myself to the largest languages and the most common phonetic realizations. (Just as [x] is an allophone of /h/ in Romanian, [h] is an allophone of /x/ in Caribbean Spanish, but [x] is the most common pronunciation and also the most referenced standard.)

Comment: @Charo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuscan_dialect#Tuscan_gorgia

Comment: /x/ para /r/ en português es del brasileño, pero para muchos (la mayoría?) es la pronunciación básica.  En Portugal, las manifestaciones alternan entre la española [r] (más en el norte y viejos) y la francesa [ʀ] (sur y jóvenes).

Answer (score 5):

The [voiced bilabial approximant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_fricative#Bilabial_approximant) [β̞] only appears to occur in other Romance languages neighbouring Basque (i.e. dialects of Catalan and Occitan (Gascon)).

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el fonema lateral palatal (/ʎ/) es un caso significativo porque es cada vez más minoritario en la propia hispanosfera. Véase la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll).

Comment: Pero el fonema /ʎ/ existe en muchas otras lenguas románicas.